# How does $\sin (\frac{3\pi}{4}) = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}$?

Tags: trigonometry

I cannot see how 
$$\sin \left(\frac{3\pi}{4} \right) = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}$$
This example has been taken from https://archive.uea.ac.uk/jtm/10/dg10p1.pdf

Please can someone show me how this is so ?

Comment: Please read this [tutorial](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) on how to typeset mathematics on this site.

Comment: Try reading "$\frac{3}{4}\pi$" as "$\frac{3}{4}$ of a half revolution"

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That's simply because $\;\sin\dfrac{3\pi}4=\sin\dfrac\pi4=\dfrac1{\sqrt 2}$

Comment: Damn, you're fast! I was just about to submit the same thing!

Comment: Great minds think together ;o)

Comment: Thanks, this has cleared things up :)